# How does Setsessiontransacted work in JMSTemplate and DefaultMessageListenerContainer with Pub/sub model

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, spring-jms, jmstemplate, message-listener

I am using a publisher/subscriber model in which I am using JMSTemplate to publish messages onto a topic. I am using defaultmessagelistenercontainer to subscribe and receive messages.

I know I can I set sessionTransacted true in both the configurations. But what happens if I put

1) only JMSTemplate setsessionTransacted true?

2) only messagelistenercontainer setsessiontransacted true?

3) both JMSTemplate and messagelistenercontainer setsessiontransacted true?

I just want to know the difference between each of these 3 things in terms of message being sent to topic and subscriber receiving the message and performing the required work with it. My core question I am trying to understand is

How long does the session last in covering these things?

*message being sent to topic and subscriber receiving the message and performing the required work with it*

Answer (score 0):

The transactions are separate. The consumer doesn't get the message until the send is committed.

If you consume a message and send another on the same thread, and both are transacted, they will both run in the same tranaaction.

Comment: So from what I understood jmsTemplate and DMLC transactions are separate.

Comment: So from what I understood, jmsTemplate and DMLC transactions are separate. So if my DMLC sessiontransaction is set to true, all the code in the onMessage() method will be done  within a transaction. What happens if there was an exception in my onMessage(). Will the message be resent to my listener and the execution happens again?

Comment: I am using a Topic not a queue

Comment: Topic Vs. Queue is irrelevant. The message is rolled back and redelivered. Indefinitely unless your broker supports dead lettering poison messages. Some brokers provide a redelivery count header.